# How does ContentPresenter work in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a problem getting a simple `ContentPresenter` to work as I expect.

When I start a new UWP project, change the `MainPage` content to

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TheContent}" />
</Grid>
```

and set it's code-behind to

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }        
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public string TheContent { get { return "Hello World."; } }
}
```

I expect the `ContentPresenter` to just create a `TextBlock` with `Text` property set to "Hello World". At least it works that way in WPF.

Instead, nothing is shown, and I have a Binding error in the output:

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'TheContent' property not found on 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1'. BindingExpression:
>   Path='TheContent' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1';
>   target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentPresenter'
>   (Name='null'); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

This looks to me, that the `ContentPresenter` tries to render it's content with the page it is located on?
When I explicitly set the `ContentTemplate` to a `TextBlock`, everything works fine, but using a `ContentTemplateSelector` that return a `DataTemplate` based on a `TextBlock`, I have the same error as before.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had a ton of issues with UWP's ContentPresenter, until I decided to switch to ContentControl instead. I don't know if it fits your usecase, but you should give it a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not creating a template then you should use the `ContentControl` The `ContentPresenter` is typically used as part of `ControlTemplate` of a`ContentControl`.

[Referencing:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.aspx)

> **Remarks**
>
> Typically, you use the `ContentPresenter` directly within the
>   `ControlTemplate` of a `ContentControl` to mark where the content to be
>   presented appears.
>
> A `ContentPresenter` is often used to apply characteristics to text
>   content, which are set into a `Content` property using only a string for
>   the text (or some indirect equivalent such as a Binding or a RESX
>   resource). For this reason the properties of a `ContentPresenter` are
>   similar to the properties of the `TextElement` class. (The `TextElement`
>   class is a base class for several elements that aren't controls but
>   are used to format the text that might appear in a control or layout
>   container.)

Remarks

When you place a `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate` of a `ContentControl`, it automatically displays the Content of the templated control. This means that if you set the `TargetType` of your `ControlTemplate` to be Button, the Content property of the `ContentPresenter` is implicitly bound to the Content of the Button that is using that `ControlTemplate`.

To set up bindings for the `ContentPresenter` properties, you may want to consider using the `ContentSource` property. The `ContentSource` property points to a property on the templated parent as well as aliases the associated template and template selector properties automatically.